# How to use goog.payments.inapp.buy with luciferous jwt?

Tags: github, google-checkout, in-app, jwt

reading this https://developers.google.com/in-app-payments/docs/tutorial

Quoted from the above page:
Because you sign the JWT using a secret key (the Seller Secret), you must generate the JWT using server-side code. It's simplest if you use a library.https://github.com/luciferous/jwt

Must I somehow include this...? I so how? there is more than one file there and no read me of what they each do, I am very confused!

The docs just don't say!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quickly test the JWT functionality you only need to include luciferous/JWT.php

You include library files using the PHP **require_once** or **include_once** statements. 
Have a look at the luciferous/tests/Bootstrap.php and JWTTest.php for an usage example.

The other files you mention are used to create the PEAR package (PEAR = PHP Extension and Application Repository). You can read more about PEAR [here](http://pear.php.net/).